# Pytools for VS 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

So I have a problem. Got a simple Python console app. It's working normally when I run it from command line by python filename.py. But when I try it in VS (pytools installed, environment configured, packages installed) I get this error:

My code looks like this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee+Shops&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA"

r = urllib2.urlopen(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html5lib")

print soup


g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})

print "\nWell, those are our cofee shops:\n"

x=1
for item in g_data:
    try:
        if item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text != "Buy on eBay Today!":
            print "%d. %s\n" % (x, item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text)
        print "Adress: " + item.contents[1].find_all("p", {"class": "adr"})[0].text + "\n"
        x+=1
    except:
        pass
```

And I get this error: [error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ru7R.png)

So I thought I will go to my New Project again and I saw, that I can install another Python Tools, but when I try to do so, i get this: [error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EplJ1.png)

Is this because I got community version ?(college student here, can get Enterprise anytime)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I had a difficult time using Python on Visual Studio. I gave up trying to do it.

I would strongly recommend you to use an IDE that is focused on python, such as **PyCharm**.

I am a fan of Visual Studio, but I have to say PyCharm is just much better for python (even on Windows).

Comment: Not quite. I frequently use it on linux and it is great - it is not as good on windows, but it shouldn't use that much resource. If this was your experience with past version, I would recommend you download the latest version and give it another try